# SQLite - Attempt to write a readonly database error

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a console application built in .net framework 4.6.2 that  manipulates  a SQLite DB in a shared path. There are times that I get an error that the database is in read-only. Nobody is updating the SQLite DB except the console app. In the console app code, all the SQLCommand are properly dispose. We also added a GC.collect code to force the garbage collection after we open an instance of SQLiteConnection.

> code = ReadOnly (8), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800017FF): attempt to write a readonly database

Here is my sample Code:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString))
{
    try
    {         
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlConnection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
         
            command.Dispose();

            sqlConnection.Close();
            System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();
        GC.Collect();
        return await Task.FromResult(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Nobody is updating the SQLite DB except the console apps" plural? If one application opens an connection to SQLite, it locks everyone else out during that brief period. This is called a Race Condition. If you have multiple applications all using the same database, you might want to consider using a database provider better suited for multiple connections.

Comment: You should not be using a single/shared/global database connection.  Create, use and dispose of it as needed preferably in a `uaing` block

Comment: @gunr2121, Only one instance of console app is running.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, I am not using single/shared connection. I always use using block for every connection

Comment: This effect may be caused by antivirus software that checks the file after it was modified. If you need to access the database file multiple times in a row, keep the database connection open instead of constantly opening and closing it